# Mapping GROUP_CONCAT returned data to arrays

Tags: php, mysql

Query:

```
SELECT a.*, GROUP_CONCAT(b.a_val) as attribute_value, GROUP_CONCAT(b.aval_id) as attribute_value_slug, GROUP_CONCAT(c.a_name) as attibute_name, GROUP_CONCAT(c.a_slug) as attribute_def_slug
FROM entries a
INNER JOIN attr_vals b ON a.sku = b.sku
INNER JOIN attr_defs c ON b.a_id = c.a_id
WHERE a.sku = ? LIMIT 0,1
```

Entries table:

[image]

attr_defs table:

[image]

attr_values table:

[image]

Expected result is getting all the attribute values, attribute name and it's slug. I am able to generate the data with the query I shown above.

Now the problem is I can explode the `GROUP_CONCAT`ed data using PHP. How can I map the exploded attribute_name data with attribute_values data.

In the screenshots shown below, the result will be,

```
$object['attribute_value']="Sample value 1, Sample value 2, Sample value 3";
$object['attribute_name']="Color, weight";
$object['attribute_def_slug']="color, weight";
```

Now how can I match Sample value 1 & Sample value 2 to Color and Sample value 3 to Weight, such that `$another_array_var['color']=("Sample value 1", "Sample value 2")` and `$another_array_var['weight']=("Sample value 3");`

Please see the screenshot why the first two values come under Color and third value to weight.